# how to add text button to action bar

Tags: android, textview, android-actionbar

I want to add textview to action bar after the logo and title like a menu item

how can I do that ?

I know how to add imageView but is it allow to add also text view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i manage to slove this with `actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable()`